# What do you think..?

Tags: domains

I am getting a paid host tommorow.

My website is a social network/forum. Its name is 'gyropanda'..
Can you give me some suggestions of a better name for my site, or if you like the current one? 
I like short and sweet names.. I can't really seem to think of a good name..

Answer (score 0):

Short and sweet names cost much, you have to be creative about you domain name.
At least buy gyropanda.com not gyropanda.co.cc

I don't think anyone here will brainstorm your new domain name (at least not for free).

Comment: Short names don't cost more than long names, unless they are already taken.

Comment: That's why you need to be creative. Sure you can register bunch of numbers and letters... Thanks for down vote ;)